# Batch import in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using the BatchInserter to insert data from a CSV file which works fine when the DB is completely empty (no files in the data directory). But using the BatchInserter I cannot get data into the database and it throws an exception mentioned below. This is with the DB service stopped. I tried several ways and failed. But I need to know if there is a way to import data from a CSV into an existing DB as the CSV is prone to change.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Misaligned file size 68 for DynamicArrayStore[fileName:neostore.nodestore.db.labels, blockSize:60], expected version length 25
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.AbstractDynamicStore.verifyFileSizeAndTruncate(AbstractDynamicStore.java:265)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.loadStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:217)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:118)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:92)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.DynamicArrayStore.<init>(DynamicArrayStore.java:64)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNodeStore(StoreFactory.java:327)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNodeStore(StoreFactory.java:316)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:160)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.<init>(BatchInserterImpl.java:258)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:94)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:88)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:63)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:51)
at net.xalgo.neo4j.batchinserter.DrugDatabaseInserter.start(DrugDatabaseInserter.java:30)
at net.xalgo.neo4j.batchinserter.BatchInserterApp.main(BatchInserterApp.java:56)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Batch Inserter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert.html) only works with initial data import (when the database is empty). It avoids transactions and other checks to increase performance and therefore cannot be used with an existing database.

For importing data into an already existing Neo4j database you can use [`LOAD CSV` Cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html).

Comment: That's a good option, but there is a problem in using this approach with what I need to. My imports are incremental, suppose my CSV today contains X rows, tomorrow it might contain X+N rows. So tomorrow I want to import just the N rows and not X+N rows. LOAD CSV will not help with that. I need a programmatic way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to remove BatchInserter and use spring data Neo4jTemplate with direct cypher in a non transactional way.